# Science fiction TV series, priest bringing Bible to spaceship?

Tags: story-identification, tv, alien-invasion

I vaguely remember seeing an episode of a Science-Fiction series many many years ago. It was something about a conquering alien race coming to Earth.

In this episode a priest brought a Bible to the alien race on their mother-ship, trying to convince them to adopt a peaceful way. The alien commander enjoyed reading the Bible, but the only conclusion he got is that one's enemies need to be crushed hard, which clearly was not the priest's intention. Unfortunately I can't remember anything else.

Can someone tell me what series this was?

Comment: Came here thinking the answer was Firefly, then read the question and decided it wasn't.

Comment: @Broklynite same! :-D

Comment: I came here thinking of Babylon 5 "And the rock cried out no hiding place"

Comment: @Kidburla - Same, but once you read the text...clearly not. One of the nice (overly-optimistic?) things about B5 was how respectful everyone was of everyone else's religion (including the atheists).

Comment: @Broklynite firefly has similar scene? :)

Comment: @T.E.D. Funny you should say that, given that a plot point of that episode was the traditional Christian being rather intolerant of the Pentecostal Christian, to the point where he practically can't stand him, despite the fact that they are of the same faith...

Comment: @Kidburla - I didn't remember that, so I went back and watched it. First off, it was a Catholic vs. a (African-American) Baptist. I guess you *could* spin it that way, but it always struck me as more shade rather than a full-blown beef. Also the difference was liturgical rather than theological. [AA Baptists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Baptist_Convention,_USA,_Inc.) tend to run their services with a great deal of animation and audience feedback (can I get an "Amen"?), and Catholics are pretty much the opposite.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think this is referring to a scene in  "V: The Final Battle" miniseries from 1984.

There is a scene when the main villain in the series (Diana) is talking to a priest (Father Andrew), after reading the bible that he gave to her. She tells him what the bible made her think and promptly shoots him.

Comment: Loved the "V" mini series and TV series when it first came out  :)

Comment: Ah yes, I remember the priests face. Although I thought that reader is some kind of reptilian alien :D Thank you

Comment: The Visitors are indeed reptilian aliens, they wear humans masks to appear more friendly iirc.  There's a scene where the main hero of the series finds this out

Comment: If Diana hadn't shot him, Robin Maxwell would have throttled him personally.

Comment: The book 'V' goes into more detail about why she decides to shoot him after reading the bible and why she considers it powerful and dangerous.

Comment: @user3559247 There is a book also? Fantastic :) Thanks

Comment: As I see 2009 series are just modern version of 1984 ones. Are they better than older ones?